# Round number Up to 0.5 and 0.25 in C# .NET

Tags: c#

How can I round decimal up to 0.5 and 0.25 ?

```
1.4 -> up to 0.5 -> 1
1.6 -> up to 0.5 -> 2

1.2 -> up to 0.25 -> 1
1.26 -> up to 0.25 -> 1.5
1.75 -> up to 0.25 -> 2
```

I have tried many ways but no success.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please share us what have you tried so far? And where did you get stuck?

Comment: It is a very strange rounding requirement, when 1.4 rounds to 1 and 1.26 rounds to 1.5

Comment: I suppose these are two different rounding requirements for different contexts? Otherwise the question would not make any sense (and a single general solution would not be possible without extra specification of the requirement).

Answer (score 0):

The first part (rounding up to 0.5) is easy (`Math.Round` function with suitable `MidpointRounding`). For the second part you can use a trivial trick:

```
    decimal[] numbers = new decimal[] { 1.4M, 1.6M, 1.2M, 1.26M, 1.75M };

    foreach  (decimal number in numbers)
    {
        decimal roundedToHalf = Math.Round(number , MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) ;
        decimal roundedToQuarter = Math.Round(number * 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 2;
        Console.WriteLine($"{number:5} -> {roundedToHalf,6} or {roundedToQuarter,6}");
    }
```

This yields:

```
  1,4  ->      1 or    1,5  
  1,6  ->      2 or    1,5  
  1,2  ->      1 or      1  
 1,26  ->      1 or    1,5  
 1,75  ->      2 or      2
```